# Return arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Dragsort plugin and we want to tag IDs in an array and print them.

My Html Code Is:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="ss"><div>1</div></li>
    <li><div>2</div></li>
    <li><div>3</div></li>
    <li><div>4</div></li>
    <li><div>5</div></li>
    <li><div>6</div></li>
    <li><div>7</div></li>
    <li><div>8</div></li>
    <li><div>9</div></li>
</ul>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

and my jQyery codes is

```
$("#list1, #list2").dragsort({ dragSelector: "div", dragBetween: true, dragEnd: saveOrder, placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>" });

function saveOrder() {
    var data = $("#list1 li").map(function() { return $(this).children().html(); }).get();
    $("input[name=list1SortOrder]").val(data.join("|"));
};

$( "#list1 li" ).each(function( index ) {
    let items = [];
    items = [ index + 1];
    console.log(items.map(() => index));
    $(this).attr("id",items);
});

$('#hamid').click(function () {
    $( "#list1 li" ).each(function() {
        its = [ $(this).attr('id')];
    });
});
```

When I want to return id `<li>` return last of them

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: problem is when i want to return all ids in "its" variable , it return just last id

Comment: You're reassigning `its` with a new array when iterating through the whole collection of `#list1 li`. Just use `.map()` to return the array of IDs in all the `<li>` elements in the click handler.

Comment: can you give me code it ?

Comment: @arman Sure. See my answer: there are two ways to do it: a basic way, and a truly jQuery way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to change the line

```
its = [ $(this).attr('id')];
//this will only create an instance of an array with one element.
```

change the last function to something like:

```
$('#hamid').click(function () {
    var ids = [];
    $( "#list1 li" ).each(function() {
        ids.push( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
    console.log(ids);  
    // this will print an array with all ids inside
    // then you can return it or do whatever you want with it
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue is that you want to get all the IDs of the elements that matches `#list1 li`, as seen in the last 5 lines of your code. The reason why it is not working is because you are reassigning a brand new array to the `its` variable. I suggest doing one of the two:

- Solution 1: Push into the array instead of reassigning it
- Solution 2: Use `.map()` + `.get()` to return an array of all IDs

---

### Solution 1 (basic)

Use `Array.prototype.push()` to append IDs to a pre-existing array. Remember that instead of converting `this` into a jQuery object and then accessing its ID via the `.attr()` method (by doing `$(this).attr('id')`), you can easily do `this.id`:

```
$('#hamid').click(function () {
    var its = [];
    $('#list1 li').each(function() {
        its.push(this.id);
    });
    console.log(its);
});
```

---

### Solution 2 (better)

Use a combination of `.map()` and `.get()`. This is the most jQuery-way to do it:

```
$('#hamid').click(function () {
    var its = $('#list1 li').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    console.log(its);
});
```

The reason why `.get()` is needed is because `.map()` returns a jQuery collection instead of an actual array. To retrieve the array itself, you will need to append `.get()` after `.map()`.